# Dismiss Keyboard not working with PickerView in the way

Tags: swift

(So far) I have two view controllers which both have at least one textfield.

When the user taps into a textfield the keyboard pops up.

I have all of the code in place to move content up and then back down again when this happens, (everything is inside of a scroll view which I am led to believe is best practice)

I also have the code in place to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps outside of the textfield.

On the first view controller it works great, but on the 2nd I have a UIPickerView that takes up a good amount of space underneath the textfield. So what happens is when the user goes to tap the most obvious amount of space he/she is actually tapping the scroll view and nothing happens. But if the user taps in a very small area that is empty and not the scroll view the keyboard dismisses.

How can I dismiss the keyboard with the UIPickerView in the way?
Here is an image of what my situation looks like 
[image: screenshot]

Here is some of the code

```
    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}

  func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: If you want to dismiss the keyboard when the picker is touched, you can simply set `picker.userInteractionEnabled = false` when the keyboard is shown, and enable it when the keyboard is dismissed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable `userInteractionEnabled` on the `picker` when the keyboard is shown (or `textField` become first responder) and enable it back when the keyboard is dismissed (or `textField` resign first responder).

Answer (score 1):

You have to resignFirstResponder .

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
```

}

Comment: I added that line of code, and it did not change anything